# If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $\sup A\le\sup B$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

**Proof by contradiction:**

By def of $\sup(A)=x$, $x$ is the upper bound of $A$ which means $x$ is an element of $A$. If $\sup A>\sup B$ then $x$ may not be an element of $B$. Hence contradiction as all the elements of $A$ need to be in $B$, as $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using $x$ and $X$ to refer to the same object, but $\sup(A) = x$ does not necessarily imply that $x\in A$.

Comment: What if i edit my proof by saying by def of sup(a) there must exist an X in A which is the upper bound of A.

Comment: That's not true in general. Recall that the supremum of a set $A$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$. Consider the set $A=(0,1)$, the open interval from zero to one excluding the endpoints. Then since every element in $A$ is less than one, every number greater than or equal to one is a valid upper bound of $A$. In particular, one is an upper bound of $A$. If you choose any number smaller than one, I can find a number slightly larger than yours but still less than one (and therefore in $A$), indicating your number is not an upper bound of $A$. Hence, $\sup(A)=1$, but $1\notin A$.

Answer (score 2):

A reminder of definitions: For a subset $S$ of a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) $P,$ an upper-bound is an element $u\in P$ such that for all $x\in S,$ $x\le u.$ An upper-bound $u$ is called a supremum when for all upper-bounds $v$ of $S,$ $v\ge u,$ and is denoted $\sup(S).$

To prove $\sup(A)\le \sup(B),$ it is enough to show, by definition, that $\sup(B)$ is an upper-bound of $A.$ That is, for all $x\in A,$ $x\le \sup(B).$ This is obvious, since $A$ is a subset of $B,$ so in particular, $x\in B,$ and the inequality is true by definition.

Comment: I am confused by the supremum and upper bound. U wrote that the upper bound is V is greater then U when U is the supremum, but I thought supremum is larger than the upper bound?

Comment: If $S=\{1,2,3\},$ then an upper-bound can be anything greater than or equal to $3,$ such as $100000.$ A supremum is just the "smallest" upper-bound, in this case, $3.$

Comment: Supremums are always upper-bounds, but not all upper-bounds are supremums.